# Showing $A= \lbrace x \in X \, \mid \, d(p,x)< \delta \rbrace$ has limit points $\lbrace y \in X \, \mid\, d(p,y)= \delta \rbrace$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. I want to show that $A= \lbrace x \in X \, \mid \, d(p,x)< \delta \rbrace$ has limit points $\lbrace y \in X \, \mid\, d(p,y)= \delta \rbrace$, for fixed $p,\delta \in X$. How do I do this in the general metric space $X$ (vs just in Euclidean space)? I'm mainly unsure of the order of the steps of the proof.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a limit point?

Comment: A point $p \in X$ is a limit point of $A$ if, for all $r>0$, there exists a point $q\neq p$ in $A$ such that $q$ is in the neighborhood of radius $r$ around the point $p$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true in general, for example if $d$ is the discrete metric on a set $X$, that is 
$$d(x, y) = \begin{cases}  1& \text{ whenever }x\neq y \\ 0 & \text{if }x=y.\end{cases}$$
Then $\{y\in X : d(y, p)<1\} = \{p\}$ has only $\{p\}$ as a limit point while 
$$ \{ x\in X: d(x, p) = 1\} = X\setminus \{p\}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample!

Answer (score 0):

Even when $\{y :r<d(x,y)<1\}$ is not empty for each $r\in (0,1)$ and $\{y :d(x,y)=1$ is not empty,the set $B_d(x,1)=\{y : d(x,y)<1\}$ may fail to have any limit points in $\{y : d(x,y)=1\} $. For example the space $\{2^{1-n} :n=0,1,2,3,...\}$  with metric $d(u,v)=|u-v|$, with $x=1$.